# Using IntelliJ IDEA for big Eclipse RTC project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, rtc

I have a big Eclipse RTC project (Eclipse 3.7, using Jazz source control, millions of files) and I'd like to open it using IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3).
Has someone experienced editing a project in IntellJ while committing changes using Eclipse?
Which precautions should I absolutely use to avoid messing up the entire project?

Comment: You should try to use maven or some other tool for this (like gradle or so). Does not rely on the project file, just version control the source and keep the eclipse and Intellij project files locally. This will make you independent on both OS and IDE and other possible environment issues. And one more thing. Scrap the eclipse 3.7. This will prevent you from going to java 8 and later java 9. Use a later version of eclipse.

Comment: @patrik unfortunately I cannot change project related files (like build systems) and I cannot upgrade to any other IDE (meh..). I'd use a portable version of IntelliJ. It's a legacy project.

Comment: In that case the things are broken to begin with. I have no experience with this, but it sounds pretty much like you trying to fix a broken space craft with chewing gums. Anyway, no need to reply on this and no pun intended. I understand that there can be issues sometime. Lets hope someone else can help.

Comment: @patrik Hahaha you nailed it! Thank you anyway. Just trying to have a more relaxed and updated development environment and IntelliJ provides all what I need (it includes also features of DataGrip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Committing changes with Eclipse (in your repository workspace, or delivering to the stream) should have no impact with editing with IntelliJ.

You will just switch between the IDE in order to assign your changes to the right change sets before committing.

That being said, you could check if the [Rational Team Concert Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7102-rational-team-concert-integration) is compatible with your current IntelliJ 2017.x.

Comment: Thanks. My biggest fear is IntelliJ changing Eclipse projects configuration files, thus screwing up the project for Eclipse.

Comment: From what I know, it should not.

Comment: I loaded the project, or better, the projects. It's working fine! I tried the RTC plugin but it is no more maintained since 2015 (I had to modify the bytecode to try it out) and everything is a error. I think I will build my own

Comment: Just so you know, IBM is preparing a real plug-in, finally

Comment: Great! Is there any link announcing that work in progress?

Comment: There is this RFE you can follow. If you look at all the linked Work Items you'll find some screenshot and ideas.
https://jazz.net/jazz/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/358932

I posted my toughts here. If you have some suggestions you could post too

Comment: It's nothing. Ah btw, in the end I managed to use IntelliJ over a big EAR (multiple EJB + multiple WAR) project but for something Eclipse is still better (like the WebLogic integration and the helpful parameter naming even without sources, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191409 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125988)